# Multiple choice questions in pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I want to be able to ask the pdf viewer a multiple choice question when he visits page X.

Can someone please give me a high level of how that can be achieved using [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library (or other library)?

I am thinking there should be a way where my front-end detects that user now scrolled to page X and thus executes the javascript function to ask the question. Am I on the right track?

I will further build on your reply. I have done my homework before posting here.

Comment: "I will use your reply as a starting point of my self-learning." -- no, SO works backwards from that. You start learning and we help, not the other way around.

Comment: @djechlin - Yes, a prompt that asks for user's feedback. For example, a prompt with multiple choice question. Does that help you?

Also, I changed my description for you. Sorry, I didn't mean to say that I did not do my HW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.scrollTop()` (jQuery) to see how far a user has scrolled through a page:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($('.pageX').scrollTop() > 0) {
       /*JavaScript to be executed*/
    }
});
```

I have given page X a class of pageX, and the instance that page X fills up the entire window your JavaScript will start.

`.scrollTop()` looks for how many pixels of the element are above the page (out of site), so if you wanted your functions to begin before the window is filled with page X you can change the `0` to a negative number, eg. `if ($('.pageX').scrollTop() > -70)` will start your javascript when page X is filling up most of the window.

Comment: Thankyou. Let me try this out!

Comment: +1 for cool stuff you explain